# malloc undefined

Tags: c, header, malloc, undefined

I am currently working on rewriting a linked list module and I am receiving some weird errors.

In two IDEs (Netbeans & Visual Studio Express), I am getting a warning that *malloc* is undefined and that a function found in my linkedlist.c file is not defined either.

below are my 3 files.

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "linkedlist.h"  
int main(void){  
 struct linked_list * l_list;   
 l_list = new_list();  
 printf("%i", l_list->length);  
 getchar();  
 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);  
}
```

linkedlist.h

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H  
#define LINKEDLIST_H  
struct linked_list{  
 int length;  
 struct linked_list_node * head_node_ptr;  
};  
struct linked_list_node{  
 struct linked_list_node * prev_node_ptr;  
 struct linked_list_node * next_node_ptr;  
 struct linked_list_data * head_data_ptr;  
};  
struct linked_list_data{  
 struct linked_list_data * prev_data_ptr;  
 struct linked_list_data * next_data_ptr;  
 void * data;  
};  
struct linked_list * new_list();  
#endif
```

linkedlist.c

```
#include "linkedlist.h"  
struct linked_list * new_list(){  
 struct linked_list * temp_list = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));  
 temp_list->length = 5;  
 return temp_list;  
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am unsure if this is a syntax issue or missing files on my computer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Where do you include `<stdlib.h>` — because that is where `malloc()` is declared?

Is this a compilation problem (`malloc()` undeclared) or a linking problem (`malloc()` undefined)?

What exactly is the error message?

---

Now the code is readable:

- `<cstdlib>` is a C++ header (so is `<cstdio>`).
- You need to include `<stdlib.h>` in C.
- You need to include `<stdlib.h>` where the `malloc()` function is used — in `linkedlist.c`.

You also <s>have</s> had the header guards in the wrong place in `linkedlist.h`, but the code in the question has been updated since. Originally, the sequence was:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H  
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#endif
struct linked_list{
…
```

The canonical structure for a header file is:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

...the other material in the header...
...definitions and declarations...

#endif /* HEADER_H_INCLUDED */
```

The `#endif` is the last non-comment, non-blank line in the file — not the third.

---

Your data structures are extraordinarily complicated for even a doubly-linked list.  Are you sure you're going to be needing the length so often that it warrants maintaining the pointer to the head in every node in the list?  I'd be surprised if you are using it that often.  I assume that you have the pointer-to-head in each node so that when you remove an arbitrary node from the list you can decrement the length of the list.  You'd probably be better off passing a pointer to the list and the pointer to the node to be deleted than what you've got.

I can see no justification for the `length = 5` in the `new_list()` function.

---

Also, C and C++ differ radically on the meaning of:

```
struct linked_list * new_list();
```

In C++, that means "`new_list()` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `struct linked_list` pointer".

In C, that means "`new_list()` is a function with a completely indeterminate argument list that returns a `struct linked_list` pointer".  The function is declared, but there is no prototype for the function.

In C, you should write:

```
struct linked_list * new_list(void);
```

Personally, I prefer to see `extern` in front of function declarations in headers; it is not actually necessary for functions, but since it (`extern`) is (or should be) necessary for variables declared in headers, I prefer the symmetry for functions declared in headers.

Comment: cstdio/cstdlib was an error on my part.
I will change the preprocessor guards so that they are in the correct place and try it again.
The linked_list_data * head_data_ptr is to the head data pointer not to the head of the list, sorry I really must comment more.
The length = 5 is simply for testing, When I run this program even though it gives me errors the output is still whatever I set the length to in the function.

Comment: The `void *data` element should be in `linked_list_node` and then you don't need `linked_list_data` at all.  You should also set `temp_list->head_node_ptr = 0;` in the `new_list()` function.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it appears you are on a Windows machine. You may have to do:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

in order to have malloc() available.

Answer (score 1):

`cstdlib` and `cstdio` are not standard C headers.  Perhaps you meant `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

you must use  `malloc()` like below:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++){
   item *temp = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item));
   temp->data = i;
   pre->next = temp;
   pre = temp;
}
```